# Two way binding for a control in a radgrid editform that conditionally binds if the dataitem is of derived type

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, radgrid, table-per-type

I am running into the classic can't use Bind in C# problem below. I can't use eval because I need 2-way binding. This textbox is sitting inside a rad grid edit form.

```
      <asp:TextBox ID="tbxTotalDepth" runat="server"
      Text='<%# (((GridEditFormItem)Container).DataItem is MS_Wells) 
      ? Bind("TotalDepth") : "" %>'  MaxLength="200"></asp:TextBox>
```

Again, I know I can't use the above, and know its because of what bind is. However, I have to do something. Here is my use case:

I am using the Table per Type structure, and want one grid for the master list on the base type. I have crud working on the base class, but can't get data binding going on any of the derived fields. More specifically, if it is of type MS_Well then bind works fine, and the gird crashes if it is not of that type because the column doesn't exist. I know I could do it on the back end, but once I have 10 - 15 columns for each derived type...... That gets messy.

I have thought of several options, but not sure the cleanest, or how to really do any of these.
1. Load a new editformtemplate after creation, basically create a new command column for 'derived details'
2. write a function to remove all of the offending controls from initializing if they are not of the correct type
3. some other form of conditional binding?

Looking at my textbox, I don't even need it at all if it the dataitem is NOT an MS-Well, but visible and enabled = false doesn't stop it from trying to bind.